Вылетает kde connect при запуске его на телефоне
Сегодня переустановил кеды и настроил себе kde connect.. все успешно законектилось но когда открываю саму программу после повторного подключения выкидывает из нее. Если что у меня android 14, пробовал сбрасывать приложение до заводских, не помогло.

У меня всё норм. андроид 14 , кде конект 1.32.4 из плейстор. кде нет - использую с гномом и с виндой
